# Initializing doubles in a loop giving error "variable might not have been initialized"

Tags: java, if-statement, variables, double

This program is supposed to get the weight of some mail from the user and calculate how much it costs. After 100g, the cost increases by $2.5/50g. However, when I try to run the program, it says "variable cost might not have been initialized". Is this because I am innitalizing it in an if statement or something? I know some people have had errors because they declare the variable in the if statment, but I have declared my variable outside the if statement. What am I doing wrong.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        double mailWeight;
        double cost;

    System.out.println("How much does your mail weigh (g)");
        mailWeight = in.nextDouble();

        in.close();

        if (mailWeight > 0 && mailWeight <= 30) {
            cost = 4;
        }else if (mailWeight > 30 && mailWeight <= 50) {
            cost = 5.50;
        }else if (mailWeight > 50) {
            double x = mailWeight - 100;
            if (x >= 50) {
                double y = x/50;
                Math.ceil(y);
                double z = y * 2.5;
                cost = z + 7;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(cost);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not get initialized if the last else if statment occures and x < 50 or when none of the if statements result in true for mailWeight. You could preinitialize cost. (double cost = 0) Or you could add all missing else blocks. You need to initialize your variable in all possible cases before reading it.

This would probably work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    double mailWeight;
    double cost;

    System.out.println("How much does your mail weigh (g)");
    mailWeight = in.nextDouble();

    in.close();

    if (mailWeight > 0 && mailWeight <= 30) {
        cost = 4;
    } else if (mailWeight > 30 && mailWeight <= 50) {
        cost = 5.50;
    } else if (mailWeight > 50) {
        double x = mailWeight - 100;
        if (x >= 50) {
            double y = x/50;
            Math.ceil(y);
            double z = y * 2.5;
            cost = z + 7;
        } else {
            cost = 0; // Or whatever you want to set it to in this case
        }
    } else {
        cost = 0; // Or whatever you want to set it to in this case
    }
    System.out.println(cost);
}
```

Or preinitializing the cost value:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    double mailWeight;
    double cost = 0; // Or whatever you want it to be if none of the cases match

    System.out.println("How much does your mail weigh (g)");
    mailWeight = in.nextDouble();

    in.close();

    if (mailWeight > 0 && mailWeight <= 30) {
        cost = 4;
    } else if (mailWeight > 30 && mailWeight <= 50) {
        cost = 5.50;
    } else if (mailWeight > 50) {
        double x = mailWeight - 100;
        if (x >= 50) {
            double y = x/50;
            Math.ceil(y);
            double z = y * 2.5;
            cost = z + 7;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(cost);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the `variable not initialized` issue, there are some more places to improve:

1. remove redundant checks
2. fix calculation of overweight cost
3. `Scanner` based on `System.in` does not need to be closed

```java
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("How much does your mail weigh (g)");

double mailWeight = in.nextDouble();
double cost;

if (mailWeight <= 0) {
    cost = 0;
} else if (mailWeight <= 30) {
    cost = 4;
} else if (mailWeight <= 50) {
    cost = 5.50;
} else {
    cost = 7;

    if (mailWeight > 100) {
        double y = Math.ceil((mailWeight - 100) / 50.0);
        cost += 2.5 * y;
    }
}
System.out.println(cost);
```

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the error, you have not initialized those two variables "mailWeight" and "cost"

Since they are local variables (inside a method) you need to initialize them before accessing them. You initialize by attributing an initial value:

```
double mailWeight=0;
double cost=0;
```